# YouTrack rest api - Get fields metadata

Tags: youtrack

I want to create issues with the youtrack rest api,
Currently I'm using:

```
PUT /rest/issue?{project}&{summary}&{description}&{attachments}&{permittedGroup}
```

but I want to set other fields (priority, type, subsystem...)

How do I get a list of available fields from the api? and the fields metadata(is mandatory, field type...)?

And after that, How do I set the value of these fields?

I found this in the docs:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Apply+Command+to+an+Issue

but it looks too complex for setting a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue can be created with following method and fields set only https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Create+New+Issue . So as you mentioned, it's

```
PUT /rest/issue?{project}&{summary}&{description}&{attachments}&{permittedGroup}
```

It's assumed, other fields can be updated within next call. ApplyCommand (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Apply+Command+to+an+Issue)method is pretty good example of such a method.

If you need to know all available fields in the projects, here is the method https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/GET+Project+Custom+Fields.
Meta can be called with the following https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/GET+Project+Custom+Field. As you can see, details are available on per field basis.